# Mi pregunta es sobre el archivo .git de mi repositorio local y el porque aumentó de tamaño de forma considerable

Tags: git, bitbucket

Les comento, tengo un proyecto web en bitbucket  que tiene aproximadamente dos meses de creación, con varios commit y varios branch, lo que no puedo precisar es porque hoy al hacer git pull origin master en mi repositorio local derrepente empieza a descargar muchos megas de información, siendo que no habia realizado cambios importantes en el repositorio remoto ni subido archivos pesados, y de 50 mb aumentó a 250 mb mi proyecto, revise y dicho tamaño se debia a la carpeta .git oculta en el proyecto, queria saber si alguno tuvo ya esa experiencia y como logró solucionarlo, gracias!

Comment: `.git` no es un archivo, sino una carpeta. Podrías tratar de averiguar si algún archivo dentro de ella es especialmente grande. Ten en cuenta que si en algún momento añadiste un archivo grande al repositorio, aunque luego lo hayas borrado, seguirá en el historial del mismo, y por tanto en la carpeta . git. Por otro lado entiendo que no hay nadie más que tú con acceso al repositorio bitbucket, que haya podido subir algo.

Comment: Excelente tu acotación, llegué a pensar en esa situación también después de realizar la pregunta, pero como somos un equipo con varias personas accesando al repositorio por ahora ya es difícil precisar dicha situación

Answer (score 2):

En .git es donde GIT guarda todos sus objetos, referencias, índices, historia. Es el repo completo, lo de fuera es la foto de un estado concreto. 
Como Git guarda una copia completa de cada cambio (y no un diff como hace SVN) se lleva mal con binarios...
Lo que me lleva a preguntar: versionas código o documentos?
Si es lo segundo puede ser la causa, aunque dices que no subiste nada pesado...

Prueba `git gc` que el el *garbage collector*.

Comment: Muchas gracias, mediante este comando pude disminuir el tamaño del proyecto (66 mb menos)

Comment: Por ahora me quedo con la idea de que se pudo haber subido algún archivo muy pesado en algún momento, y aunque fue borrado se quedó en el historial de versiones.

Comment: Eso es así, efectivamente, aunque lo borres está en el historial. Te puede ayudar a deshacerte de eso `git clone --shallow-since=<date>`que tal y como dice la documentación:
_Create a shallow clone with a history after the specified time._ Pero yo esto ya lo haría con cuidadín...

Comment: Gracias, lo veo como algo interesante, pero por ahora no podré aplicarlo, igual muchas gracias por la observación!